# Not able to write files from one xml to another xml using java

Tags: java, xml

Actually i need to replace some of the tags in source xml and write the files as new one. Here my code works fine but now am not able to open the output xml. In the output xml i have some tamil words. Is it the reason for file not opening

```
 public class dxml {

  public static  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer() ;

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    File xmlFile = new File("/home/dev702/Desktop/axl/Data Entry.xml");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("/home/dev702/Desktop/axl/Data Entry.xml"));
    String line = null;
    int linecount = 1; 
    FileWriter fw;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    fw = new FileWriter("/home/dev702/Desktop/axl/Data_Entry_OPT.xml") ;
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
           if(linecount > 2)
            {
                line = line.replaceAll("Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date",
                                                                "DataEntryDate");
             //bw.write(line);
            }    
         bw.write(line);
         linecount++;
         System.out.println(line);
      }
    bw.close();
    fw.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: am not getting any error but the new file not opening

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: am not doing many things am just replacing a word with new word

Comment: xmlFile variable is useless in your code

Comment: File not opening - does it mean that file is not created? And do you see file content on console (printed in loop)?

Comment: i used that xml only to read and write. May i know why you are saying useless in my code

Comment: yes i printed that in my console word not replaced

Comment: I do not see that you use this variable in your code. You might wanted to write BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlFile)) ..

Comment: Where are you closing your Reader?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform XML to another form of XML you should be using XSLT's to achieve this. Java has support for transforming two documents...below is a code snippet of how to acheive this.

The premise really is you get your original XML into a document, set up the XSLT to use and transform it into another document.

The scope of using XSLT is outside of this reply. I recommend using Altova's excellent XMLSpy for testing your XSLT's.

```
public class Mapper {


public Document convert(Document originalDocument, Resource xsltResource) throws TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException,
        JAXBException, IOException, SAXException {

    /**
     * You'll need to create your documentBuilder to build the new document.
     */
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    /**
     * Set up your transformer factory, you'll need to pass your XSLT file in as an inputstream
     * I've passed it in here as a method arg and it's a Spring Resource but you can do it however you like.
     */
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
            .newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltResource.getInputStream()));

    /**
     * Set the encoding to avoid headaches.
     */
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");


    /**
     * Create a BAoS to hold your original document.
     */
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(originalDocument), new StreamResult(os));

    /**
     * Do the transformation.
     */
    return documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(os.toString("UTF-8"))));

   }
}
```

Comment: for this where can i get input file and output file..can you plz elaborate

Comment: Hi, so in your case the input file is /home/dev702/Desktop/axl/Data Entry.xml the XSLT would also be a file. You'd need to convert your XML File into a Document object. Google can help you do this and your for your XLST file you'd need to get it as an InputStream. Your output (after transforming) would be a Document object which you could then write out to a file.